# Can I determine if a user has a browser add-on enabled?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf-viewer

I am using a PDF viewer in an MVC application, `object id='pdfbox'`. For this to work an add-on has to be enabled in the browser: Adobe PDF Link Helper.

Is it programmatically possible to determine if the add-on is enabled or not in the client machine and give to link to enable the add-on?

Is any sample code available?

Comment: Why would you want to block people from reading a PDF in their favourite PDF reader application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try providing alternate content which will be displayed if the plugin is not installed:

```
<object ...>
    <p>
        You do not have the XXX plugin installed. You could download it here
    </p>
</object>
```

Comment: Dude, i read all (most of) your answers to questions. u rock!

Comment: But before that how to determine if the plugin is installed or not in the client machine

Comment: Simply put: **you can't**. That would be violation of the privacy: you, as a web application developer, are absolutely not supposed to know what plugins people have installed/enabled/disabled on their computers. You could ask them prior to navigating to the web page that requires this plugin or if you don't want to ask them, simply leave the client browser handle the default content if it cannot find the requested plugin.